# How To Create Your Own Basic WordPress Widgets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am beginner in wordpress, I found many plugin for to create widgets but i want to create a custom text and RSS widgets same like Widgets that comes with every WordPress installation. It allows users to add text, video, images, custom lists, and more to their WordPress sites. what should i do for that.

Comment: Please check this url for your question - https://jainsagar.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/how-to-create-your-own-basic-wordpress-widgets/

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is regarding my widgets that one i want to create custom please support us to learn more

Comment: @animuson please support us to get more answer from community people. i want to learn more about this please support us as i am beginner.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Put This code in themes -> function.php
register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'custom-widget',
    'name'        => __( 'Custom Widget', $text_domain ),
    'description' => __( 'This is custom widget.', $text_domain ),
));

//After place code to function.php you can see your widget in your dashboard widget.

//Place This code where you display your widget
if (function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && 
    dynamic_sidebar( sprintf( 'custom-widget', $i ) )
)
```

Comment: last code is optional if you want to display widget then use this code otherwise done.

Comment: thanks for your support

Comment: Your requirement is done with my code?